Validating a Request in a Spring Security Filter
I have a filter which need to read the request body with this code
override fun doFilterInternal(
    request: HttpServletRequest,
    response: HttpServletResponse,
    filterChain: FilterChain
) {
    val data = request.reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining())
    val loginRequest = ObjectMapper().readValue(data, MyRequest::class.java)

However, the request class has some validations.
class MyRequest {

   @Email
   var email: String? = null

   @Min(1000)
   var userNumber: Int? = null
}

So these validations shall be validated inside the filter, not on the controller.
How can I use some kind of standard validator to validate all fields programatically

Not exactly sure what you are asking, but does this help : Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator().validate(loginRequest)

@sidgate This is the idea, thanks
